# Microsoft purview API call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-purview

I'm looking to integrate Microsoft's Purview DLP in my web application. My application sends email so I want to block any sensible information from being sent.

Basically a user is going to be under a Microsoft Purview policy to prevent data losses. I want to integrate his DLP policy within my web application.

My two main question were: Is there an Api call that can retrieve then sensitivity label of a certain document of a user? And is there an Api call that can scan a document or string with the regex expression of Microsoft Purview?

**Example:** Let's say I want to send an email with a document, I want to see through an Graph Api call if we can retrieve the sensitivity label of Microsoft Purview of a certain document linked to a specific user. Then I want to scan the email content and the document content with Microsoft's Purview regex expression to see if there's any sensible information within the email. Ideally scanning the data would be an Graph Api call with a string containing the document and email content and then getting the response from the Api if the email can be sent or not.

Is there a way to do this? All the documentation I found was pretty basic and wasn't answering my questions.

Answer (score 0):

To get the sensitive label through the API:

```
GET /users/{usersId}/security/informationProtection/sensitivityLabels/{sensitivityLabelId}
```

or

```
GET /me/security/informationProtection/sensitivityLabels/{sensitivityLabelId}
```

For more info:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-sensitivitylabel-get?view=graph-rest-beta#http-request